# How to obtain a List<double> that is inside an List<object> element (c#)

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<object>`, and its first element is a `List<double>`, I mean:

```
//----

List <object> lista = new List<object>();

List <double> listain = new List<double>();

Lista.Add(listain);


//---
```

Now I want to obtain the data that is in `lista[0]` (this element is the `List<double>`), but I don't know how to do it; I've tried with a `foreach`, but that doesn't work with objects.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
foreach (double item in lista [0] as List<double>)
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var item in lista.Cast<List<double>>())
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, to answer your questions:
You have to cast the first element into the right class

```
foreach (List<double> doubleList in lista){
    foreach(var number in doubleList){
    // do whatever you want 
    }
}
```

Second, why do you cast your `List<double>` into and list of  `object`s if you already use templates?

try to define the list like this:

```
List <object> lista = new List<List<double>>();
```

It doesn't change the programming but it makes it a lot clearer to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast that element to your desired datatype. This way.

```
List<double> col = (List<double>) lista[0];

for (i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it - so:

```
var doubleList = (List<double>)objectList[0];
```

Alternatively if you don't know for definite that it will be of that type, you can do

```
var doubleList = objectList[0] as List<double>;
if (doubleList != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is only to contain lists of doubles you should use:

```
var doubleList = List<List<Double>>();
```

Adding would be like:

```
var double = 1.1;
var insertList = new List<Double>();
insertList.Add(double);
doubleList.Add(insertList);
```